# Property does not match property type in primary class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with m file since iOS 8 (but works on iOS 7), I need this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *description;
```

But in NSObject.h I have this :

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *description;
```

And Xcode returns this error -> "Type of property 'UITextView *' in class extension does not match property type in primary class"

I think I must change the name of my UITextView but I'm not sure.

Can you give me some advices, please?

Comment: Never name a method or property `description`. It will conflict with the NSObject method.

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding the `NSObject` description property unless it actually returns a string description. Just name your property something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to change the name of your `UITextView`, I'd go for `descriptionTextView` or something similar.

What's happening here is that `NSObject` [already has a property named `description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description). Since the object you're setting this property on likely inherits from `NSObject`, the system apparently thinks that you're trying to extend `NSObject`. Since it's property type is `NSString` and you're trying to define a property of type `UITextView`, the compiler balks and decides that it can't work. So you get this error.

What probably happened is the compiler got smarter with iOS 8 than it was in iOS 7, and thus catches this error. Either way, it's in your best interest to change it!